# How to control the number of errors displayed in the Message Window in toad

Tags: plsql, toad

I am trying to compile a package in the DB. I know that there are many errors in it. But for some reason Toad only displays the first 10 errors at a time. If i correct some of the errors, it displays again the list of the next 10 errors.

So my question is, is there any way for me to see all the errors during the first time i compile the procedure/package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shown with the limit rows highlighted applies only to script execution (F5/lightning bolt button) and not to compiling with F9/button with green arrow. Following a compile Toad queries ALL_ERRORS or USER_ERRORS if you are logged in as the schema owning the object. The result set is not limited. Those errors you are seeing may be all that Oracle has logged. It may not be able to detect error farther downstream due to the ones found already.

Comment: Specifically, this query is executed. SELECT line, position, SUBSTR (text, 1, 200) text
FROM SYS.ALL_ERRORS
WHERE name = :oname AND TYPE = :otype AND owner = :oowner
ORDER BY sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can try to query `dba_errors table`: this table contains all the errors that occurred in the last compilation of an object.

For example to see all errors occurred during the compilation of an object called `my_object_name`:

```
select * 
from dba_errors 
where upper(name) = upper('my_object_name')
```

Please note that this second solution isn't Toad specific, but should achieve what you need.

Comment: I think the first part of your answer is to limit the number of records retrieved when running as a script.
But the second part(the query) was helpful. Thanks...

Comment: @rapidclock: you're right, I removed the first section